TypeScript AntDesign filterDropdownProps Doesn't Work
I wanted to give custom filterDropdownProps to my Table Column (I am using Ant Design table) to be able to apply filter on selection (not by pressing the 'Ok' button. I did as shown on the Ant Design documentation, but it doesn't work. I tried with multiple options (not just the menu option) to see if they work, and none of them did.
const columns: ColumnsType<TagCombinationPublic> = [
    {
      title: "Cluster",
      dataIndex: ["cluster", "tag"],
      key: "cluster",
      filters: clusters?.data.map((tag) => ({
        text: tag.tag,
        value: tag.tag,
      })),
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.cluster.tag === value as string,
      filterMultiple: false,
      filterSearch: true,
      filteredValue: filter.cluster? [filter.cluster] : null,
      sorter: (a, b) => a.cluster.tag.localeCompare(b.cluster.tag),
      sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === "cluster" ? sortedInfo.order : null,

      // Here, I give the dropdown props
      filterDropdownProps: {
        menu: {
          onSelect: ( key ) => {
            setFilter({ ...filter, cluster: key.key })
          },
          selectable: false,
        }
      }
    },
    ...
]

I am using React 18.2.0 and antd 5.22.0
